# Ubuntu Server file transfer configuration

Tags: ethernet

I have a desktop computer (Ubuntu Server) and a laptop (Lubuntu desktop).

I want to use an ethernet cable to directly connect the two and use the Server to network all my storage media and serve it to my laptop via the ethernet cable.

I've seen tutorials on how to connect two computers by creating an IP for them in nm-applet.

My question is how to do this via the command line on Ubuntu Server?

Also, I don't want a lot of overhead. I don't see the need to use ssh when there is no internet connection.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, there are multiple ways of doing that. If you want to do this using the command line, I suggest you use rsync (through ssh. It is always good to use ssh, also in a LAN.) or you could mount the volume on your server so it appears on your laptop as a drive. Try to be more specific in what you would like to achieve. (Make sure your server has a static internal IP address in the LAN.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need a crossover cable to connect a network card to another network card, unless any of the network cards has feature "autosensing". Normal ethernet cables are only good to connect network card to a hub.

To configure your server you will need to edit file /etc/network/interfaces. Check out this guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html